# Как в Android 4+ включить GPS программно?

Tags: android, java

Как в Android 4+ включить GPS программно?

Comment: надеюсь что такого способа нету.

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте. Google говорит, что есть способы, но я нашел только для устройств с root.

- [Enable GPS programatically like Tasker 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305835)
- [Enable GPS programatically like Tasker 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11503095)
- [How to enable GPS in android coding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5481752)

Для устройств, где нет root, лучше всего просить пользователя, что бы он вручную включил его и если он захочет включить GPS, то переводить пользователя на страницу настроек, где находится кнопка включения GPS.

Comment: У меня сейчас стоит стандартный виджет энергосбережения. Там отключается gps  в один клик.

Comment: Ну извини, я знаю то, с чем сталкивался. Жди, может кто то более опытный, поможет тебе.

Answer (score 0):

никак в 4+ они эту дырку прикрыли. (и правильно, так как если я выключил GPS , зачем какому то приложению минуя мои желания включать его)

Но, в 2.х можно.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы менять настройки в `Settings.Secure` (к которым относится GPS), необходимо иметь права рута или являться системным приложением (лежат в `/system/app/`)